# Darknet YOLOv4 training - does it print every every image, every batch, every subdivision? Getting weird numbers

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, object-detection, yolo, darknet

When I train yolo v4, I get a lot of outputs that I later want to use to plot learning rate changes.

With max_batches = 1543 darknet prints 74064 outputs (with loss etc, I don't count outputs with mAP calculation, network definition etc).
With batch = 32, subdivisions = 16, I have only 49376 itarations (defined as single images passed through network)!

Something is definitely off, does anybody know how often this binary is supposed to print values?

```
./darknet detector train data/obj.data ../yolov4-custom.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -dont_show -map &> logs.txt & disown
```

```
[...]
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, cls: 1.00) Region 139 Avg (IOU: 0.000000, GIOU: 0.000000), Class: 1.000000, Obj: 0.000000, No Obj: 0.000000, .5R: 0.000000, .75R: 0.000000, count: 1, class_loss = 0.500000, iou_loss = 0.000000, total_loss = 0.500000 
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, cls: 1.00) Region 150 Avg (IOU: 0.394489, GIOU: 0.289983), Class: 0.985003, Obj: 0.004027, No Obj: 0.000896, .5R: 0.000000, .75R: 0.000000, count: 6, class_loss = 3.253636, iou_loss = 0.891068, total_loss = 4.144704 
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, cls: 1.00) Region 161 Avg (IOU: 0.612244, GIOU: 0.555591), Class: 0.897004, Obj: 0.014743, No Obj: 0.000339, .5R: 1.000000, .75R: 0.000000, count: 1, class_loss = 0.492179, iou_loss = 0.095293, total_loss = 0.587472 
[...]
```

Comment: Did you check the number of output in your logs.txt file?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the outputs from binary are printed in [yolo_layer.c](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/yolo_layer.c). Yolo v4 has 3 yolo layers.
The batch size recorded by yolo layers = 2 (global_batch_size/subdivisions).
16 forward passes per batch * 1543 batches * 3 prints per forward pass = 74064

Which makes sense.